# Write all Summands for function with a Taylor Formula

Tags: calculus, functions, partial-derivative

I need to write all for this function $f:\mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ $$f(x,y) = x^{2}+2y^{2}+2xy-6x-8y+11 $$

all summand with this Taylor formula:
$$f(x + \xi) = \sum_{|\alpha| \leq k}  \frac{ D^{ \alpha } f(x) }{\alpha!}\xi ^{\alpha }+(k+1)\sum_{|\alpha| = k+1}\int _{0}^{1} (1-t)^{k}  \frac{ D^{ \alpha } f(x + t\xi) }{\alpha!}\xi ^{\alpha }dt$$

for $X=(x_{0},y_{0})$ from part a, for any $\zeta=(\zeta_{1},\zeta_{2}) \in \mathbb{R}^{2} $ and $k=2$.

In part a of this Problem i calculated the only critical point of the function at $(x,y)=(2,1)$

This task makes me sick. I don't understand it.

As far as i know is that $D^{\alpha}f(x)$ is the multi index partial derivative of function $f$. At least i think so :-)

Can anyone help me and give a hint?

Comment: "Can anyone help me and give a hint?" It looks like you're getting confused by your own terms. Is your $x$ a real value, or, a tuple of values? It looks as if you've set a trap for your own mind ;-) .

Comment: yea it is really a mess here ^^ i think x is representing any inputs for a function f. My function has x,y so it should be something like f(x,y+\xi) or so. I know i don't use the best terms but maths is not one of my strength.

Comment: So your $x$ in the book from the Taylor formula relay is a vector and is only incidentally named *x*, but, as far as I understand the details from afar, is really your $(x, y)$ from your $f(x,y)$. $x$ is not a universal constant, it varies from context to context.

Comment: yes right. i think this is so. but i am not really sure

Comment: $f(x_0+\zeta_1,y_0+\zeta_2)=?$. Note that the Taylor series of a polynomial is just that polynomial. For this one problem, forget about all differentiation and integration.